# What are main components of webservices to be learned ? And how to deploy a webservice on servers such as Apache etc?

Tags: web-services, tomcat, webserver

I am new at webservice and i want to know where and when should webservices be used and exposed?

And what it takes to deploy and use webservices (wsdl file) on Tomcat or any other servers ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From technology agnostic things the important knowledge is the stack composition: WS-(Servlet)-HTTP-(TLS)-TCP/IP (optional layers in parenthes). As a platform you typically try some lightweight option like Jetty or Winstone before falling back to the Apache Tomcal.

If you are after *any* webservice now, then a wise thing to do is just pick some mature Java standard technology like JAX-WS. There will be a good tutorial on java.net, respective Maven packaging and deployment plugins and IDE integration rigs. Once you have a simple thing working you'll have more specific questions most answered on SO.